# Enable Remote Desktop File Transfer

Tags: remote-desktop, file-transfer

Most of the servers I RDP to support cut-and-paste file transfer (from my Win7 64 machine).  One does not, and I can't figure out what configuration step is missing.

I followed the steps outlined here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/how-to-gain-access-to-local-files-in-a-remote-desktop-session-to-a-windows-xp-based-or-to-a-windows-server-2003-based-host-computer-021ee183-e6be-4201-809e-c355c47b17f4

but do not see the local file system on the remote server (or vice versa for that matter), and I cannot cut and paste files from the local to the remote system.

If I try to cut and paste from the remote system to the local one, I get the error

> Cannot copy FILENAME: Windows cannot
> find '%1!ls!'.  Check the spelling and
> try again, or try searching for the
> item by clicking the Start button and
> then clicking Search.

The remote server is Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition.

Comment: Hi Eric. I am also having this problem for some time. Wondering if you managed to solve this problem?

Comment: If you open an explorer window on the remote server and enter \\tsclient\c\ as the path, does it enumerate your local hard drive? If so there may be some other issue, otherwise its certainly a config problem.

Comment: The URL in this question now redirects to https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/how-to-gain-access-to-local-files-in-a-remote-desktop-session-to-a-windows-xp-based-or-to-a-windows-server-2003-based-host-computer-021ee183-e6be-4201-809e-c355c47b17f4 - but I haven't edited the new URL in yet as I haven't yet checked to see if the content has changed significantly.

Comment: @AJM Thanks. The steps look to be the same. Updating the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is no RDP policy setting preventing you from connecting the local drives to an RDP session, on the client (before you connect) go into the option/local resources and ensure the drive(s) is/are enabled. On the Win 7 client you will need to click the "More" button to see the drives option.

Comment: Did that per the link in my post.  Where would I check policy settings on the remote server?

Comment: @EricJ. I believe that's set in the Terminal Server Manager MMC plugin.